# MySql to return Distinctive record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written the following sql statement, on test table, i have 4 records and on the coa_body table i also have four records, this query:

```
SELECT `name`, `compedia`, `specification`
  FROM    (`tests` t, `coa_body` cb)
  JOIN
      `request_details` rd
    ON `t`.`id` = `rd`.`test_id`
 WHERE `rd`.`request_id` = 'NDQA201303001' AND cb.labref = 'NDQA201303001';
```

returns:

1.name                     compedia   specification

```
Assay                     Alphy     poxy
pH(Acidity/Alkalinity)    Alphy     poxy
Sterility                 Alphy     poxy
Bacterial Endotoxin Test  Alphy     poxy
Assay                     poxy      alphy
pH(Acidity/Alkalinity)    poxy      alphy
Sterility                 poxy      alphy
Bacterial Endotoxin Test  poxy      alphy
Assay                     alphy1    poxy1
pH(Acidity/Alkalinity)    alphy1    poxy1
Sterility                 alphy1    poxy1
Bacterial Endotoxin Test  alphy1    poxy1
Assay                     poxy1     alphy1
pH(Acidity/Alkalinity)    poxy1     alphy1
Sterility                 poxy1     alphy1
Bacterial Endotoxin Test  poxy1     alphy1
```

2.coa_body table is as follows:
    id  labref         compedia specification

```
1   NDQA201303001   Alphy   poxy
2   NDQA201303001   poxy    alphy
3   NDQA201303001   alphy1  poxy1
4   NDQA201303001   poxy1   alphy1
```

3.I only need 4 records exactly the same as the coa_body table like this

```
   name                     compedia   specification

   Assay                     Alphy  poxy
   pH(Acidity/Alkalinity)    poxy   alphy
   Sterility                 alphy1 poxy1
   Bacterial Endotoxin Test  poxy1  alphy1
```

4.at the end of the query if i add GROUP BY t.name statement, it  returns

```
 name                   compedia  specification     

Assay                       Alphy   poxy
Bacterial Endotoxin Test    Alphy   poxy
pH(Acidity/Alkalinity)      Alphy   poxy
Sterility                   Alphy   poxy
```

which is not want i want, the result that i want is the one at number 3

Comment: Please no not use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: Ok, ill keep that in mind next time

Answer (score -1):

Rewriting your query

```
SELECT `name`, `compedia`, `specification`
  FROM    (`tests` t, `coa_body` cb)
  JOIN
      `request_details` rd
    ON `t`.`id` = `rd`.`test_id`
 WHERE `rd`.`request_id` = 'NDQA201303001' AND cb.labref = 'NDQA201303001' GROUP BY name;
```